# BIT_XOR ,cast_to_raw equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle11g, sql-server-2008-r2

please suggest:
BIT_XOR ,cast_to_raw equivalent in SQL Server.

I need to change below code from oracle to sql server:
:newRow.userid := (utl_raw.bit_xor(   utl_raw.cast_to_raw(:newRow.userid), utl_raw.cast_to_raw(TransportInfoPackage.key)   ));

Comment: FYI, SQL Server 2008 (R2) reach end of life over a year ago, and you should be looking at upgrade paths ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Using equivalent form [Exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or):

```
DECLARE @i INT = 1;
DECLARE @j INT = 3;

SELECT i = @i, j = @j, xor = (@i | @j) & (~(@i & @j));
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1c80ce6d83950153e1c5c09f9bc4d6e0)**